# Model Association using rails3 way

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am making association like,

I have three tables.

```
   Product, Category

    p1 ----> c1(1)
    p1 ----> c2(2)
    p1 ----> c3(3)

    p2 ----> c2(1)
    p2 ----> c3(2)
    p3 ----> c4(3)
```

---

each category of product is in order(sorting). Order of product category should not repeat.

In this case I have tried product `has_many :categories` and `category has_many :products` using `through :xyz table`. But order of category remains same on last change.

I want to create an association between product and category and order the rails 3 way

Comment: How do you want to order the categories? Alphabetically? In the order that they were selected via creating the `xyz` association?

Comment: categories should be order in numeric field. when I give product.categories it should give me list of categories which I set sort_order as numeric value.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean about ordering.

Comment: Order means admin can set sequence of categories for that product.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your join table is called `product_categories`, you could just add a `sort` column to the join table.

Then you can set your `has_many through` association like so:

```
has_many :product_categories
has_many :categories, through: :product_categories, order: 'product_categories.sort'
```

Another option that may work would be to add a default scope to the `ProductCategory` model:

```
default_scope order(:sort)
```

Comment: How to set value of sort column while insert and update in view and controller